# 'git init -b <branch name>' command in terminal is throwing an 'unknown switch' error

Tags: xcode, git, macos-catalina

I am trying to add an existing project to GitHub using the command line. I am in the relevant working directory in the terminal and am trying to use the `git init -b main` command.

Initially, I was getting an error relating to xcode:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I tried `xcode-select --install` but the software was unavailable from the update server, so I downloaded 'Command Line Tools for Xcode 12' from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

Now on entering `git init -b main` I am getting the following:

```
error: unknown switch `b'
usage: git init [-q | --quiet] [--bare] [--template=<template-directory>] [--shared[=<permissions>]] [<directory>]

--template <template-directory>
                      directory from which templates will be used
--bare                create a bare repository
--shared[=<permissions>]
                      specify that the git repository is to be shared amongst several users
-q, --quiet           be quiet
--separate-git-dir <gitdir>
                      separate git dir from working tree
```

I am running git version: 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Just say git init and then change master to main if you want to.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`git` 2.24](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init/2.24.3) doesn't have option `-b`/`--initial-branch`. It was added in [`git` 2.28](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init/2.28.0). You need to upgrade to use the option.

Or, as @matt said, create a repo and then rename the branch:

```
git init repo
cd repo
git branch -m master slave
```

Comment: `error: refname refs/heads/master not found. fatal: Branch rename failed` Instead:  `cd repo; git checkout -b main`

Comment: @RobinA.Meade I saw that a commit must already exist so the branch `master` exists

Answer (score 70):

The `-b` flag is only available in version 2.28 or later, you need to upgrade your Git.

On debian-based Linux systems such as Ubuntu, do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git -y
```

Answer (score 36):

### prior to git v2.28

```sh
git init                              # ①
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/main # ②
```

① After `git init`, the branch `master` does not actually exist. Branches get created only when they have at least one commit.

② This updates `.git/HEAD` to contain `ref: refs/heads/main` instead of `ref: refs/heads/master`. Alternatively, `git checkout -b main`.

### git v2.28+

As @phd said, the `-b/--initial-branch` option was added in git v2.28. git 2.28 also introduces a config option to specify your preferred default branch:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

Learn more about the new `init.defaultBranch` setting in [GitHub's blog post](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch).

Answer (score 16):

In case you need to install the latest `git` version (in Ubuntu)

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/YuMS/6d7639480b17523f6f01490f285da509

Answer (score -2):

This is happening due to the unavailability of a tool called Xcode Select, running `xcode-select --install` in your terminal fixes these issues with Git not working.